# How to write defaultdict in more pythonic way?

Tags: python, defaultdict

How do I write this in Pythonic way :
counts_to_display is a defaultdict(dict) which has following data:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>,
            {'server01': {'metric1': 9},
             'server02': {'metric1': 12},
             'server03': {'metric3': 8}, 
             'server04': {'metric1': 11, 'metric2': 7}
            })



headers = []
for count in counts_to_display:
        for name in counts_to_display[count]:
                if name not in headers:
                        headers.append(name)
```

I need to print everything in a table:

```
Server   Metric1 Metric2 Metric3
server01    9       0       0
server02    12       0       0
server03    0       0       8
server04    11       7       0
```

Comment: If the order doesn't matter change `headers` to a `set`. That is the best you can do I guess.

Comment: Which output do you expect? Your code doesn't clarify this.

Comment: @wenzul added my expectation in the question

Comment: Please write a list/dict whatever, what you expect. The code doesn't clarify to me what you expect because it results `['metric1', 'metric2']`.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. Table header.

Comment: Yes, the dict I have is big and I did not want to use nested for loops to get the headers.

Comment: Ok, but if the metrics are not that much than you can kind of neglect the inner loop because you have lets say just 3 metrics but 1k servers. So it depends on each loops count. A generator also uses "nested for-loops" internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
headers = {key for count in counts_to_display.values() for key in count}
```

I'm using a set instead of a list since we're working with a dictionary as input, which has arbitrary ordering anyway, so it wouldn't make sense to want to keep ordering intact, and sets automatically take care of deduplication for us, while being more performant for certain operations, too.

You could use the following, too:

```
import itertools
headers = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(counts_to_display.values()))
```

Comment: `itertools` is kind of overkill for that simple call... ;)

Comment: I myself would prefer the set comprehension, too, but I'm pretty sure that `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is more readable, and easier to wrap your head around. There's no significant cost to neither that import, nor to using `itertools.chain()` so I'd say it's a perfectly reasonable piece of code to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` along with `reduce` to get you job done

```
headers = set(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [count_to_display[count].keys() for count in count_to_display]))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `reduce`? Should be one of the fastest solution.

```py
print sorted(reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, servers.itervalues()).keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
>>> d = {'server01': {'metric1': 9},
         'server02': {'metric1': 12},
         'server03': {'metric3': 8}, 
         'server04': {'metric1': 11, 'metric2': 7}
        }
>>> dicts = [x for x in d.values()]
>>> result = reduce(lambda d, src: d.update(src) or d, dicts, {})
>>> result
{'metric3': 8, 'metric2': 7, 'metric1': 11}
>>> res = [r for r in result.keys()]
>>> res
['metric3', 'metric2', 'metric1']
```

Comment: Using a `dict` is redundant here, because a `dict` already has unique keys.